# Omit comments from heredoc

Tags: bash, heredoc

I'm trying to write multiple lines of text into a file using `cat <<EOL`. I would like to ask if it's possible to comment out lines of text inside of that command. If I use a `#`, it still gets printed into the file.

```
cat >$HOME/myfile <<EOL
text
# text to be commented out
text
EOL
```

Comment: This is not a "cat eol command". This is a heredoc.

Comment: The heredoc is a file, not a script processed by `bash`. There are no comments, just text.

Answer (score 2):

Comment *lines* can be omitted by using `grep` instead of `cat`:

```
grep -v "^#" > myfile <<EOF
# line omitted
but this whole line is # included, with the comment too
EOF
```

If you want to delete everything after a `#` you can use `sed` as in the other answer, but do decide carefully what you want to do to the left over white space: does it get deleted or included in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with `sed`:

```sh
cat <<EOF |  sed '/^#/d' > myfile
Hello
# there!
World
EOF
```

will write `Hello\nWorld` to `myfile`

Comment: You don't need `cat`

Comment: True, but given the OP called a "heredoc" a "cat eol command", I don't think they are bash experts and I don't think this is the proper time to try to teach them about useless use of cat. I think it's more clear to OP with this sort of piping set up. I know this was more clear to me when I was first learning.